# compiling multiple java files in node.js

Tags: java, node.js

I tried to compile 3 java files in a row.

```
A.java
B.java
C.java
```

and B.java mentions class A in its code.

By using `setTimeout`, I compiled A and waited for 10 seconds.
Then compiling B has started.
However, B has compile error,

```
symbol A cannot be resolved.
```

when I try doing the same thing, in a same order by myself in terminal, it worked fine without any compile errors.
Could you tell me what is wrong?

below is code segments;

```
const child_process = require('child_process');
/* ... */
function compileThreeFiles(dirPath, req, res) {
  child_process.exec(`javac ${dirPath}NodeJsInput.java`, (err) => {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err);
      res.json(resJson);
      return;
    }
    setTimeout(function() {
      child_process.exec(`javac ${dirPath}Robot.java`, (err) => {
        if (err) {
          console.log(err);
          res.json(resJson);
          return;
        }
        setTimeout(function() {
          child_process.exec(`javac ${dirPath}Main.java`, (err) => {
            if (err) {
              console.log(err);
              res.json(resJson);
              return;
            }
            setTimeout(function() {
              executeMain(dirPath, req, res);
            }, 10000);
          });
        }, 10000);
      });
    }, 10000);
  });
}
```

Robot.java has a reference of NodeJsInput class, and compiler says NodeJsInput : cannot find symbol.

Comment: So you're running this compilation through the system command line via Node.js right?

Comment: yes, I used child_process. I edited the post with my code.